# strange problem draw a label on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I used an UINavigationController pushViewController to present an ViewController, on the view of the viewcontroller, there is an UITablView.
I used the codes below to draw UILabel on UITableViewCell, but it does not display, only when I tap the row where the UIlabel is, it will appear, if I tap another row, it disappear again.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   

            static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier1 = @"CellTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier1 ];
    if  (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero       
                                                 reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier1] autorelease];
        switch([[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getValueType])
        {
            case _PSToggleSwitchSpecifier:  

            {           
                UISwitch *switchview=[[UISwitch alloc]init];

                switchview.tag=11106 ;
                cell.accessoryView= switchview;
                 //switchview.frame=CGRectMake(80.9f,15.0f,80.0f,23.0f) ;
                //[cell.contentView addSubview:switchview];
                [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

                [switchview release];   
                break;
            }
            case  _PSMultiValueSpecifier:
            {
                cell.accessoryType=  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;//

                //draw a label, but actually it does display,  
                UILabel *labelCell =[ [UILabel alloc]init];
                [labelCell setTag:11101];
                labelCell.frame = CGRectMake(80.9f,15.0f,80.0f,23.0f) ;
                [labelCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                labelCell.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
                [labelCell setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
                [labelCell setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:labelCell];
                [labelCell release];

                break;

            }
        }       
    }    

    cell.text=@"test";

    switch([[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] getValueType])
    {

        case _PSToggleSwitchSpecifier:  
        {
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;//

            UISwitch *tem=(UISwitch*) [cell.contentView  viewWithTag:11106];//cell.accessoryView;// 
            tem.on= true;
            break;

        }
        case  _PSMultiValueSpecifier:
        {
            UILabel *newLabelCell=(UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 11101];//intV];
            newLabelCell.text=@"Items";//it should display, but actually not, only when I tap the row "didselect" the text display
            break;

        }
    };

    return cell;
}
```

In codes above UISwitch are displayed, but if I use codes

```
switchview.frame=CGRectMake(80.9f,15.0f,80.0f,23.0f) ;
[switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[cell.contentView addSubview:switchview];
```

to replace `cell.accessoryView= switchview;`

UISwitch will be the same thing as UILabel

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using initWithStyle to create your UITableViewCell...

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

Note: initWithFrame deprecated, and you're using a CGRectZero for the frame